# Postgresql Locking Rows on a Key/Foreign Key

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, dml

I'm using postgresql.  I have 3 tables.

- **Table A** has an ID column that's a Primary Key
- **Table B** and **Table C** have ID columns that are foreign key references to A's ID.

In a single process, I would like to lock any rows that have a particular ID and then possibly delete rows and insert rows with that ID in B and C

My current approach is

1. SELECT FOR UPDATE on A on the ID.
2. Then I try to delete and insert rows in B and C.
3. commit/end

Unfortunately, my code deadlocks trying to do the insert.

What am I doing wrong?  What is the proper way to prevent other processes from adding, removing, or updating rows with a given ID in B and C (until I am done with my transaction)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks I was doing things correctly from the start.  My issue was that I was accidentally creating two different database connections in my code.  So, from postgresql's perspective, there were two different transactions - hence the deadlocking.

Comment: Ah... your approach was correct. That's the way of doing it.